# Finding the fewest a value appears in two arrays at once in Ruby

Tags: ruby

For a project in Ruby I need to compare arrays and keep the fewest a value appears, for example:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 1]
b = [1, 2, 2, 3]
```

would result in `[1, 2, 2]`, because the 2 appears at least twice, 1 appears at least once and 3 only appears in one array.

I tried doing it with the `&` operator, but it doesn't keep the duplicates:

```
a & b #=> [1, 2]
```

The answer could be recorded in hash form, with a element itself as a key and number of occurrences as value.

Maybe make a hash with 0 as the default value and keep the minimum number of occurrences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start by counting each occurrence via [`tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally):

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 1]
b = [1, 2, 2, 3]

h1 = a.tally #=> {1=>2, 2=>2}
h2 = b.tally #=> {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1}
```

Both hashes can then be combined via [`merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) with a block, which is called whenever a key exists in both hashes. The block's return value determines the final value for that key: (here: the lower value)

```
h1.merge(h2) { |k, v1, v2| [v1, v2].min }
#=> {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1}
```

This already works fine for keys `1` and `2` but unfortunately, key `3` is also present in the merge result.

However, since the block is *only* called for duplicate keys, we can use a little trick and store the duplicates in a separate hash instead: (ignoring the return value from `merge`)

```
result = {}
h1.merge(h2) { |k, v1, v2| result[k] = [v1, v2].min }

result
#=> {1=>1, 2=>2}
```

To expand this back into an array:

```
result.flat_map { |k, v| [k] * v }
#=> [1, 2, 2]
```

You can omit the `h1` and `h2` variables by inlining them, i.e.

```
result = {}
a.tally.merge(b.tally) { |k, v1, v2| result[k] = [v1, v2].min }
result
#=> {1=>1, 2=>2}
```

You could even incorporate the result hash using [`with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) with a little help from [`enum_for`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Object.html#method-i-enum_for): (although it looks quite ugly)

```
a.tally.enum_for(:merge, b.tally).with_object({}) { |(k, v1, v2), r| r[k] = [v1, v2].min }
#=> {1=>1, 2=>2}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple more options:

Here's one using `flat_map` to iterate over the intersection of `a` and `b`;

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 1]
b = [1, 2, 2, 3]

(a&b).flat_map{ |num| [num] * [a.count(num), b.count(num)].min}
#=>  [1, 2, 2]
```

As you can see, it uses the `count` and `min` methods to figure out which of the 2 arrays has the lowest count of each number.  The numbers are added to the resulting array by a multiple of that result using [Array#*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-2A).

---

And here's a very similar approach to create the requested hash instead of an array;

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 1]
b = [1, 2, 2, 3]

(a&b).map{ |num| [num, [a.count(num), b.count(num)].min] }.to_h
#=>  {1=>1, 2=>2}
```

The syntax is very similar and uses the same basic approach but this time we just used the standard `map` method to iterate over the intersection of `a` and `b`.  For each matching array element, a new 2 element array is generated.  The first element is the number present in both source arrays, and the second element is the minimum quantity of times that number is present in either `a` or `b`.  The resulting 2 element arrays are then converted to a hash using [Array#.to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h).

Comment: Again, this is computationally excessive. If, for example, `(a&b).size #=> 100` you are making `100` passes through `a` and `b`, where you should be making only a single pass through each array to count the number of instances of each unique element of the array, represented in a *counting hash*. The hash's keys are the distinct elements of the array and the values the associated counts.

Comment: Ya, I realize its not the best answer.  Just throwing a couple other options out there.  In particular, I have a soft spot for people stuck using older ruby versions.  I'm working in an environment where Ruby 2.4 is hard coded into the software package and therefore ```tally``` isn't available.  I'm forced to find other options myself so I like to throw out alternatives just in case.  Plus as I'm sure you know, they can come in handy for future users that may need something slightly different from the OP.

Comment: Before `tally` was added we would write (for example) `[1,2,4,2,1,1].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x,h| h[x] += 1 } #=> {1=>3, 2=>2, 4=>1}`, which has the same computational complexity as `tally`. One could also write `[1,2,4,2,1,1].each_with_object({}) { |x,h| h[x] = h[x].to_i + 1 }`. as `nil.to_i #=> 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The *natural* way to do this in my mind is like matching up playing cards from 2 hands.  I would want to go through `my_hand` one `card` at a time checking to see `if` there is a match in the `other_hand`.  If a match is found, the `card` is taken away from the `other_hand` and set down as a `pair`.  If no match is found, then the `card` is ignored.  Using that same logical approach, here's what we can do:

```
arr_1= [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
arr_2 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def find_pairs(my_hand, other_hand)

other_hand = other_hand.dup

pairs = my_hand.select{|card| card & other_hand.delete_at(other_hand.index(card)) if other_hand.include? card}

end

find_pairs(arr_1, arr_2)
#=>  [2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Here it is reduced to its critical elements and applied to the original example:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 1]
b = [1, 2, 2, 3]

c = b.dup

a.select {|num| c.delete_at(c.index(num)) if c.include? num}
#=>  [1, 2, 2]
```

I'm really not a fan of having to create a copy of the original array but I can't think of any other non-destructive way to use this approach.

Comment: I think you mean `a.select {|num| c.delete_at(c.index(num)) if c.include? num}` as [Integer#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-26) is *bitwise and*. That's a bit obtuse, however. Though more lines, I think something like `a.select {|num| rv = c.include?(num); c.delete_at(c.index(num)) if rv; rv }` would be more clear...

Comment: ... My main point, however, is that you are doing a lot of work when compared to first computing a *counting hash* for each array, using [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally), as @Stefan and I have done in our answers. The computational complexity of `tally` is nearly `O(n)`, where `n` is tne size of the array.

Comment: Thanks Cary, I made that correction to remove the unnecessary ```num &``` code section.  I'm not actually sure why that was in there.  I imagine I was playing with some other options and that was a carryover from doing so.  And I do completely agree that the ```tally``` approach is much better.  This option was entirely an exercise in writing a solution based completely on everyday real world logic.  I just find it to be a good skill to practice.  Plus it offers other ideas to play with that may be handy for other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Stefan, I first apply [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) to both arrays to produce *counting hashes*, which provide counts of each unique element in the array, but I do not merge the resulting hashes. I then just step through each key-value pair of the first hash to build the array that is to be returned.

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 1, 4]
b = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

```
h1 = a.tally #=> {1=>2, 2=>2, 4=>1}
h2 = b.tally #=> {1=>1, 2=>3, 3=>1}
```

```
h1.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),a|
  n = [v, h2.fetch(k,0)].min
  a.concat([k] * n) if n > 0
end
  #=> [1, 2, 2]
```

See [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) and [Array#*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-2A).